# Calculate the 1 in a value

Tags: algorithms

I am getting different values from a computer program that I designed. I then want to formulate an algorithm to calculate the 1th value below it (and I'm not really sure the terminology for this so bear with me).

Examples if I have:
43535 the result = 10000, 
76765 = 10000, 
5674 = 1000, 
344 = 100, 
56 = 10, 
8 = 1, 
0.435 = 0.1, etc.

If someone could educate me a little that would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers are called powers of ten.
To decide which one, calculate M=floor(log(N)/log(10)).
Lastly, if you want, calculate 10^M.